# How to get the percentage of occurences of a certain variable for a specific value of another variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

For a research project I'm doing I'm using a dataframe that has approximately 950.000 rows and 52 variables. I have one outcome variable which is a medical condition. Another variable is a number (id) that is connected to a certain hospital. I now need to find what the percentage is of the people that had the medical condition per hospital. So for each hospital I have to get a percentage of the patients that did have the condition and the percentage of the patients that did not have the condition.

I created a new dataset that contains only the medical condition variable and the hospital id variable. Lets say this dataset is called dataset, the outcome variable is called outcome and the hospital number is called id. The code below did give me the percentage of the occurrences of each hospital id, but since there are 765 different hospital id's this did not help me.

```
prop.table(table(dataset$id))*100
```

I also tried to use group by with the following code:

```
group_by(dataset, outcome) %>% mutate(rc = n()) %>% group_by(id, outcome) %>% mutate(percent_observed = round(n() / rc, digits = 4) * 100)
```

This did give me a percentage of how many of the total population patients had the medical condition at that specific hospital, but it did not give me the percentages I want.

I thought that maybe a for loop or an if statement would be helpful, but I don't know how to use these in this particular situation since there are so many different possible values for the hospital id variable. Does anyone know how I can get the percentages?

I can not provide a real example of my dataset since it contains confidential information, but I tried to create one that is similar:

| **outcome** | **id** |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 245 |
| 0 | 376 |
| 1 | 245 |
| 0 | 43 |
| 1 | 245 |
| 1 | 4 |

With this example dataset I would like to see that 67% of the patients in the hospital with id 245 the patients have the medical condition and in the hospital with id 4 100% has the medical condition.

Comment: This would be far easier to help if you could provide an example of your data set.

Comment: @Phil I just added an example of my data set (or at least tried to create one that is similar)

Comment: `dataset |> group_by(id) |> summarize(perc = sum(outcome) / n())`

Comment: @Phil I forgot to mention that outcome is a factor and id is numeric. So when I run that solution I get the following error: Problem with 'summarise()' input 'perc'.  'sum' not meaningful for factors.

Comment: `dataset |> group_by(id) |> summarize(perc = sum(as.numeric(levels(outcome))[outcome]) / n())`